# Close popup in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a code which renders a popup to a marker using `leaflet` and it's as follows.

```
const lat = e.latlng.lat;
   if ($('#lmap').css("cursor") === 'crosshair') {
      const note = `<div>popup<div>`;
      const newMarker = new L.marker(e.latlng,{draggable:true}).addTo(lmap);
      if (!(note === "")) {
         newMarker.bindPopup(note, {closeOnClick: false, autoClose: false, closeButton: true}).openPopup();
      }
   }
```

Here

```
closeButton: true
```

is used to render a close button in my popup. But the problem is popup closes when i click on the marker also. How can i prevent closing of the popup when clicking on the marker and just to close it when clicking on the close button in the popup.

Answer (score 1):

Don't add the popup directly to marker, create a popup "layer" and open it, when clicked on the marker:

```
// a global variable
var popup = L.popup({closeOnClick: false, autoClose: false, closeButton: true});


//your function from above
const newMarker = new L.marker(e.latlng,{draggable:true}).addTo(lmap);
newMarker.on('click',(e)=>{
    popup.options.offset = e.target.options.icon.options.popupAnchor;
    popup.setContent('TEST').setLatLng(e.target.getLatLng()).addTo(map)
})
```